# Subspace dimension, polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

When finding the dimension of subspace **A = {a + bx + cx2 + dx3| a + b + c + d = 0}** with space of polynomials of degree at most 3.

How do I go about this? I do know how to proceed when given vectors or matrices, but I am not sure how to exactly proceed with this subspace.

Comment: You can translate this to a problem of coordinate vectors. It's the set of $(a,b,c,d)$ in $\mathbb R^4$ such that $a+b+c+d=0$. Note that this condition says $d=-a-b-c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the proposed constraint, one has that $p(x)\in A$ iff
\begin{align*}
p(x) & = a + bx + cx^{2} - (a+b+c)x^{3}= a(1 - x^{3}) + b(x - x^{3}) + c(x^{2} - x^{3})
\end{align*}

Consequently, the set $\{1-x^{3},x-x^{3},x^{2}-x^{3}\}$ spans $A$ and is LI. Thus $\dim(A) = 3$.